# AVA unit tests fails passed Javascript test specs

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, ava, mjs

I am currently working with ES6 modules with `.mjs` extensions and creating test cases for some functions.

I have chosen `AVA` due to its support of this extension type but the test executions are not running as expected.

**I assume the script is not being transformed properly 
or 
I am missing a configuration in my `package.json`**

I appreciate any help at all from anyone with experience with using AVA with `--experimental-modules`

package.json

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "test": "ava --init"
    },
    "ava": {
        "require": [
      "esm"
    ],
        "babel": false,
        "extensions": [
      "mjs"
    ]
    }
}
```

test.spec.mjs

```
import rotate from './index.mjs'
import test from 'ava';

test('rotate img', t => {
    var m = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];
    rotate(m);

    t.is(m, [[7, 4, 1], [8, 5, 2], [9, 6, 3]]);
});
```

index.js

```
 var rotate =function(matrix) {
    let cols = 0,
     original = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(matrix));

    for (let i=0; i < matrix.length; i++){
        for (let j = matrix.length; j > 0; j--){
            matrix[i][cols]=original[j-1][i]; 

            cols+=1;
            if(cols == matrix.length){
                cols= 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
export default rotate;
```

On running `npm test` as defined in package script

> ERROR:
>
> ```
>  1 test failed
>
>   rotate
>
>    12: rotate(m);
>    13:     t.is(m, [[7,4,1],[8,5,2],[9,6,3]
>    14: ]);
>
>   Values are deeply equal to each other, but they are not the same:
>
>   [[7,4,1,],[8,5,2,],[9,6,3,],] <<fails
>
> npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
> ```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

AVA does not support `.mjs` out of the box, but it looks like you figured out the configuration.

For the `test` script, just use `ava`, without the `--init`.

All that said, the test is failing because you're using the wrong assertion. `t.is(actual, expected)` uses `Object.is(actual, expected)` (which is pretty much `actual === expected`). And you can't compare arrays like that.

Use `t.deepEqual()` instead.